# Given an equation with multiple variables, all integers, how would I minimize an extra variable (also an integer)?

Tags: functions, optimization

Consider:

$$2x + 4y + 8z + w = 75$$

Or more accurately for what I want to deal with:

$$nx + oy + pz + w = q$$

Where $n$, $o$, $p$, and $q$ are all positive integers and constant, and $x$, $y$, and $z$ are the variables being adjusted, also all positive integers. $w$ should also be a positive integer.

How would I find, whether it's an algorithm or something purely mathematical, a way to minimize $w$? That is, find the combination of values of $x$, $y$, and $z$ that results in the smallest possible $w$?

Example:

$$14x + 60y + 17z + w = 723$$

This has 20 answers, as an example one of them is $x=9, y=4, z=21$ where $w = 0$.

I think it could also be thought of like this:

$$f(x,y,z) = -nx - oy - pz + q$$

Find values of $x$, $y$, and $z$ at a minimum of $f(x,y,z)$.

Comment: This is a special case of integer linear programming, which is to minimize or maximize a linear function of integer variables subject to linear constraints on those variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the greatest common divisor $d$ of $n$, $o$ and $p$.

See how often $d$ goes into $q$. That is, write
$$
q = Ad + R
$$
with quotient $A$ and remainder $R$.

Then $Ad$ can be written as an integer combination of the integers $n$, $o$ and $p$ and is the largest such number, so $R$ is the $w$ you seek. (In your example it's $0$ since 14, 60 and 17 have no common factor so $d=1$.)

If $q$ is large enough then $x$, $y$ and $z$  can be chosen to be positive. If $q$ is not big enough you will have to do a little more work.

There are algorithms for these calculations. Look up the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) in wikipedia, scroll down to
*The case of more than two numbers*.

Comment: This doesn't work for the remainder in examples such as q = 48, n = 9, o = 18, and p = 21.

Comment: With those data the smallest possible remainder is $0$. Then $48 = 1 \times 9 + 1 \times 18 + 1 \times 21 + 0$. If you try with $q=45$ the argument doesn't work because $45$ isn't "large enoigh".

Comment: that makes sense I guess. Should it work above the sum of a, b, and c?

Comment: Not always. You can see that in this case it fails for $q=51$. What's "large enough" is a little tricky.